# How do I express ":" but not preceded by "\" in a Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

How can I express "not preceded by" in a Java regular expression?  For example I would like to search for ":" but only when it is not directly preceded by "\".  How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"(?<!\\\\):"
```

The reason for the four backslashes is:

- the backslash is a special character in regular expressions so you need the regular expression `\\` to match a single backslash.
- backslashes must be escaped in Java strings, so each of the above backslashes must be written as `\\`, giving a total of four.

Example code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\):");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo\\:x bar:y");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a character class with the complement operator?

```
    String s1 = "foo : bar";
    String s2 = "foo \\: bar";

    Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("[^\\\\]:");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

    m = p.matcher(s2);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: This fails to match `:` at the beginning of the string.